# Iphone: Difference between these two assignment

Tags: iphone, properties

i have this code in my .h:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *arrayData;
```

What is the difference between:

```
self.arrayData = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"date",@"trip",nil];
```

and:

```
arrayData = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"date",@"trip",nil];
```

and what should i use and how to release the arrayData variable.

Thanks

Comment: I think you need "when to use self": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385980/objective-c-when-to-use-self

Comment: @Evan, like this it leaks, you should also add an `autorelease`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that using `self.arrayData = ...` retains the array. You should release it using `self.arrayData = nil;`.

The code you <strike>have</strike> *had* here doesn't work, for `init` alone doesn't allocate an array. You could use

```
self.arrayData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"date",@"trip",nil];
```

To allocate and initialize the array.

**ps** the `arrayWithObjects` returns an allocated and autoreleased object. That means that the object will vanish if you don't retain it. So use `self.arrayData = ...` to do so.

The equivalent with alloc/init/autorelease would read:

```
self.arrayData = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:....,nil] autorelease];
```

Comment: [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"date",@"trip",nil]; most certainly does allocate an array.

Comment: @StefanH: someone decided to edit and fix the original question. ;-)

Comment: but when i use this: 
arrayData = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"date",@"trip",nil];

since i called alloc i have the ownership of the object, haven't i? So i need to release it too.

I don't understand the difference sorry

Comment: Yes, correct. That is a perfectly valid way. **But** if you do that again, the original object will not be deallocated (unless you would actively call `[arrayData release]`). If you use `self.arrayData = ...` twice, the first object *will* be deallocated without you doing that explicitly. That's the difference.

Comment: and a last question. If a need and empty array, is this is correct?


self.dataSource = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

thanks

Comment: 10 out of 10 points! For the bonus point, use `initWithCapacity:` to tell beforehand how much room you need.

Comment: @xger86x yes, it's correct. however, it is more common to use the convenience constructor: `self.dataSource = [NSMutableArray array];` in this specific case. you'll still use alloc+init+autorelease when a convenience constructor does not exist for a particular type.