# what is use of self in 'self.window addSubview : view '?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, uiwindow

i am new developer of iphone i want to knw what is the difference b/w these 2 statement 
statement1:

> [self.window addSubview:lscreen.view];

statement2:

> [window addSubview:lscreen.view];

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385980/objective-c-when-to-use-self/2386022#2386022

Answer (score 0, accepted):

self key word is used when we useing the property getter/setter instead of accessing the value directly. when it is generated by the synthesize key word you have to use self because the object is retained there instead of simply pointer-assigned.

Answer (score 1):

This document help you to understand self in any objective c code.

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/2/8/understanding-your-objective-c-self.html