# Use of "Self" keyword in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, oop, self

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Objective-C - When to use ‘self’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385980/objective-c-when-to-use-self)

I can't understand very well the importance and the usage of the "self" keyword in objective-c. It's my first OOP language so i got stuck on some concepts.
When i should use "self"? Why is it useful?

Thanks for the answers!

Edit: I can't understand why is this a duplicated post of [Objective-C - When to use 'self'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385980/objective-c-when-to-use-self) when there there is not the explanation of "Self" that i wanted.

Comment: I'm not reposting questions. I read the post that you linked but I have not figured it out yet.

Answer (score 16):

`self` is a special variable in Objective-C, inside an instance method this variable refers to the receiver(object) of the message that invoked the method, while in a class method `self` will indicate which class is calling.

`self` refers to the actual object that is executing the current method, it is an invisible argument passed automatically by the runtime environment to your instance methods.

Comment: For both instance and class methods, it "refers to the receiver of the message". It's just that in a class method, the receiver is a class object. Also, it only refers to that at the beginning of the method -- `self` can be re-assigned like any other local variable.