# how to use self and when to use it?

Tags: objective-c, oop

I have been making iPhone apps for a couple of month now and i still haven't really understand what self does. I know its a pointer to the receiver but that doesn't really tell me anything. I think i would understand it more if someone show me an example when i should use it and explain what would happened if i not use it. I have only been using self for calling methods.

```
[self myMethod]
// calling a method
```

Third and last question: what can I call self on expect properties and methods?

Comment: Are you familiar with any other OOP languages?

Comment: Did you try the [search function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14535527/use-of-self-keyword-in-objective-c)?

Comment: no, but i have been programming in other game languages like lua where self refers to the current "object", like an opposite to @public variables. So I'm not completely unaware in what it mean.

Comment: @Till yes i have but i haven't really found a good answer.

Comment: @Freddy the one I linked appeared to be pretty good. Especially once you also follow its duplicate - so read both and that should help a lot.

Comment: maybe you will find it helpful http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/02/08/understanding-your-objective-c-self.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a class method, `self` is a pointer to the class.

In an instance method, `self` is a pointer to an instantiated object of the class.

Let's focus on the latter, as it's the most common use of `self`.

Let's suppose we have a `Box` class.  When we want to represent a box programmatically, we instantiate an instance of the `Box` class:

```
Box *myBox = [[Box alloc] init];`
```

Now, we can instantiate as many instances of boxes as we'd like.

```
Box *greenBox = [[Box alloc] init];
Box *redBox = [[Box alloc] init];
Box *blueBox = [[Box alloc] init];
```

Now, within the `Box` class, we will have instance methods.  These are methods that are called  on instantiated objects of `Box`.  For example:

```
[greenBox someMethod];
[redBox someOtherMethod];
```

But this is an outside with a reference to a box that wants to call a method on a specific Box reference.

When a Box object needs to call a method on itself, it uses `self` as a reference to itself.

So, let's say when `someMethod` is called on a Box object, as part of `someMethod`, the Box object needs to call a method `doStuff` on itself.

So in `Box.m`, we might have:

```
- (void)someMethod {
    // doing actual stuff, then calling a method to do stuff
    [self doStuff];
}
```

Where `self` is another method within this file and we're calling it on the object for which the `someMethod` message was sent to.

This would be like the outside caller saying `[greenBox doStuff];`.

But we can use `self` in other ways.

We can use `self` to access properties of the object.  For example, consider this property in `Box.h`,

```
@property BOOL canDoStuff;
```

Now back to `someMethod`:

```
- (void)someMethod {
    // doing actual stuff then...
    if (self.canDoStuff) {
        [self doStuff];
    }
}
```

And we can also use `self` as a method argument.  For example:

```
- (void)someMethod {
    // doing actual stuff then...
    if (self.canDoStuff) {
        [BoxHelperClass doStuffWithABox:self];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very nice explanation. But why do you use (self.candostuff) instead of just (candostuff). I don't see what uses it has.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by "expect properties"?

Comment: I recommend searching up some more information about Objective-C properties.  This is an entirely different question...

Comment: So if i understand right, (self.candostuff) refers to [greenbox] in this case?

Comment: [BoxHelperClass doStuffWithABox:self]; Is this the same as [BoxHelperClass doStuffWithABox:[Greenbox]]?

Comment: It'd be similar to `[BoxHelperClass doStuffWithABox:greenBox];`