# Objective-C : Using Self to access local variables

Tags: objective-c

I'm learning Objective-C and i have a confusion about **self** ,so here is the code :
the interface :

```
@interface Person : NSObject
{
float HeightInMeters;
int WeightInKilos;
}
@property float HeightInMeters;
@property int WeightInKilos;
- (float) BodyIndex;

@end
```

the implementation without **self**:

```
@implementation Person
@synthesize HeightInMeters,WeightInKilos;
-(float)BodyIndex
{
    float h=HeightInMeters;
    float w=WeightInKilos;
    return w/(h*h);
}
@end
```

the implementation using **self**:

```
@implementation Person
@synthesize HeightInMeters,WeightInKilos;
-(float)BodyIndex
{
    float h=[self  HeightInMeters];
    float w=[self  WeightInKilos];
    return w/(h*h);
}
@end
```

so here is the question : with or without **self** both code are working fine , so what is the purpose of using self ? thanks

Comment: You should use lowercase letters at the beginning of method names and properties.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385980/objective-c-when-to-use-self

Answer (score 1):

`self` allows you to be more explicit about where the information is coming from.

For example, you could have a method like this:

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)other {
  return [self class] == [other class] && [self info] == [other info];
}
```

Also, depending on the memory semantics of your property, if you do something like `self.info = someInfoObject` the synthesized property method will manage the `retain` and `release` calls for you.

Having the `self` identifier makes it clearer. If you're familiar with Java or C++. `self` is somewhat akin to `this`.

Comment: so , this means that there is no real purpose to use Self just to be more explicit right ?

Comment: @satyres No, that's not a right conclusion to reach from this answer: there's a very real purpose behind using `self` in your example - it makes a difference between a variable access and a method call.

Answer (score 0):

you can remove @synthesize on your code.
if you remove this, you can access to your @property with self or _ :

```
@property float heightInMeters;
```

_heightInMeters or self.heightInMeters

[Here](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/02/08/understanding-your-objective-c-self.html) a link to explain how to use correctly self and what is it ;)

Comment: Thanks , so you mean that with @synthesize , i can access local variables if not we can use self ? am i right ?

Comment: Yes you can remove all your synthesize and access to your property with self.myProperty

Answer (score 0):

When you use `[self HeightInMeters]` you are accessing the *property* named `HeightInMeters`. When you just use `HeightInMeters` you are accessing the backing field for that property because of how you wrote the `@synthesize`.

See more in the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html) for properties.

Answer (score 0):

Going through accessor methods (which is what's really different here) is a fundamentally different operation from accessing an instance variable. If you don't call the method, the code in that method won't run, so none of its side effects will happen (notifying via KVO, retaining/releasing under non-ARC, doing lazy initialization, whatever you write in the method yourself).