# Group buttons together for easy manipulation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

I am trying to group related buttons together so that I can show/hide/move them all as one. I have determined that using a UIView would probably be the best bet however, when I try this the the sub view doesn't show up. I'm wondering what I may be doing wrong.

```
UIView *playerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.size.width, 50)];
[playerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorRed]];
[view addSubview:playerView];
```

Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried it. It works for me, but you need to fix one small thing:

colorRed -> redColor;

[playerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

Comment: For some reason it was because i did 

    `[view addSubview:playerView];`

Instead of 

    `[self.view addSubview:playerView];`

Not sure why though, I thought they were the same thing.

Comment: Read the answer to this post (the one by @bbum) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302891/self-instance-var-performance-hit

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that view.frame.size.width is > 0 at that time? Where does that code get executed?

Try using a number for the width instead of view.frame.size.width and see if you get different results.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can see in your code that might cause this is if the view.frame.size.width is 0.
Is "view" itself visible?